# Run rake task in another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I have a `ruby on rails` `api_app` and and a `test_app` that exercises the `api_app`. While development mode I want to run, from the `api_app`, a rake task called `match:reset` that is in the `test_app`.  I am trying to do this with a ruby file that is in the `api_app`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'tty-command'
cmd = TTY::Command.new
Dir.chdir('../test_app') do
   cmd.run 'run rake match:reset'
end
```

When I do this I get the following error

```
 Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

I have tried adding `cmd.run 'rvm use 2.4.1'` but this does not work.  How do set the correct environment so this does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this working with a ruby command file. I think the reason  for this is that the file is run with ruby from the `api_ppp` directory so you cannot change to another ruby.  What I ended up doing is using a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../test_app
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 2.4.4@test_app_2.4.4
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=../test_lab/Gemfile bundle exec rake -f ../test_app/Rakefile match:reset
```

I am happy to consider an answer that uses a ruby command file, as long as the answer has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not tested, based on the documentation I have made changes to the script.

```
require 'tty-command'
require 'rake'

cmd = TTY::Command.new
cmd.run("rvm use 2.4.1")
Dir.chdir("../test_app") do
  cmd.run(:rake, 'match:reset', env: {rails_env: :development})
end
```

Comment: The ```rvm use 2.4.1``` fails saying that ```/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@api-app_2.4.4/bin' is not at first place``` and when the rake tast runs it states ```/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@api_app_2.4.4/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:491:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)``` so it looks to me that I am running the right rake file but with the ruby from the ```api_app```

Comment: I think the issue is with the path. Can you check, if you can run this `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`, before `cmd.run("rvm use 2.4.1")` or you can also try `rvm reset`, if in case the path does not work.

Comment: I ran ```ls = `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"``` before the rvm command and the value of ls was "- "?

Comment: I also tried ```rvm reset``` before the ```rvm use 2.4.1``` and it gives the same error.

Comment: Ok, can you try running this ? `system("source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm")` before `rvm use 2.4.1`

Comment: This does not work either. I think the fundamental problem is that I am using a ruby command file, so ruby is already being run from the ```api_app```.  I will try two things, first updating the ruby in the ```test_app``` to 2.4.4 and if that does not work, using a standard bash file instead of a ruby file.

Comment: You can try another option with your other two, is you could write all the commands in a `.sh` and then call that in a `ruby` script.

Comment: Yes that could work (see my answer below), it would allow me to do the other actions in ruby.